# Select and group by by fields forcing to group by but then not grouping properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I've been working with this query, but I can't understand why is not grouping properly (showing only combinations of company and zip. but forcing me to group by email as well, how can I do so it groups by company and zip only?

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(o.Company), 
       o.Zip, 
       o.Email,
       --RIGHT(Email, LEN(Email) - CHARINDEX('@', email)) AS Domain, 
       cv.EmailDomain, 
       COUNT(o.OrderNumber) AS ordernumber, 
       YEAR(o.OrderDate) AS TheYear, 
       FORMAT(cv.DateVisited, 'MM-yyyy') AS [DateVisited], 
       cv.MeetingType
FROM dbo.CustomerVisits cv
     JOIN dbo.Orders o ON o.Zip = cv.Zip
WHERE(RIGHT(o.Email, LEN(o.Email) - CHARINDEX('@', o.email))) = cv.EmailDomain
GROUP BY o.Zip, 
         o.Email, 
         o.Company, 
         cv.EmailDomain, 
         o.OrderDate, 
         FORMAT(cv.DateVisited, 'MM-yyyy'), 
         cv.MeetingType;
```

right now is giving this as result:

[image]

and giving 260+ rows when the "customervisits" table has only 30+ rows
I've been trying to reduce fields in the select, but I need them to be able to filter and pivot later (plus I need to do some manipulation on the select still)

Comment: Remove all the unaggregated columns except for company and zip.

Comment: you mean from the select of from the group by? I need them in the select and it gives me error when taking them out of the group by

Comment: Your group by must contain everything in your select that isn't contained within something like SUM() or MAX(). Also distinct and group by are redundant. You're getting more than 30 rows because your join is matching multiple times so it's copying rows to get all possible joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you group by company and zip, your data will not allow duplicates at that level. If you are fine with using any email for the company and zip, then:

```
 SELECT o.Company, 
       o.Zip, 
       max(o.Email) as Email,
       max(cv.EmailDomain) as EmailDomain, 
       COUNT(o.OrderNumber) AS ordernumber, 
       YEAR(max(o.OrderDate)) AS TheYear, 
       FORMAT(max(cv.DateVisited), 'MM-yyyy') AS [DateVisited], 
       max(cv.MeetingType) as MeetingType
FROM dbo.CustomerVisits cv
     JOIN dbo.Orders o ON o.Zip = cv.Zip
WHERE(RIGHT(o.Email, LEN(o.Email) - CHARINDEX('@', o.email))) = cv.EmailDomain
GROUP BY o.Zip, 
         o.Company
```

The above statement will pick the maximum value for all the fields if there are multiple values. Hope this helps.